# Is it possible to pass bind variable as parameter?

Tags: oracle, plsql, bind-variables

Is it possible to pass a bind variable to a procedure? Here a simplified snippet, to show what I'm trying to do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_CSV ( :d1 IN DATE DEFAULT null, :n1 IN NUMBER DEFAULT null)
IS 
BEGIN    
    SELECT DISTINCT * from table WHERE MY_NUM = :n1;    
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood how procedures work.

You define a procedure (or function) with parameters, the values of which get passed in from the calling code.

Therefore, you would define the procedure with named parameters, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_CSV (d1 IN DATE DEFAULT null,
                                      n1 IN NUMBER DEFAULT null)
IS 
BEGIN    
    SELECT DISTINCT * from table WHERE MY_NUM = n1;    
END;
/
```

and you would call the procedure passing in the values - which could be bind variables, e.g.:

```
BEGIN
  test_csv (d1 => :d1,
            n1 => :n1);
END;
/
```